# Discrete Logarithm Problem in Finite Fields

Tags: finite-fields

Consider the finite field $\mathbb{F}_{\displaystyle{3^{23}}}$ which is constructed from the primitive polynomial ${\bf f}=x^{23}-x^3+1$ over $\mathbb{F}_3$. Let $\alpha$ be a root of $\bf f$. Suppose that $\beta$ is a polynomial based on the $\alpha$ such as $\beta=\alpha^{22}+\alpha^{21}+\alpha^{11}+1
$.

*My question:* Is there a method (except full search)
to find a positive integer number $k$ such that 
$\beta=\alpha^{k}$?

I know my question is a kind of discrete logarithm problem, but I have no idea except exhaustive search to answer.

Thanks for any suggestions

Comment: Index calculus may work. [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2289111/11619) is an example run, though in a much smaller field. I'm fairly sure I don't want to try that in your case (without a serious silicon aide) unless the polynomial factors easily.

Comment: $3^{23}-1=2\cdot47\cdot1001523179$, so Chinese remainder theorem is not going to really help. Baby step - giant step will give you square root order reduction. Pollard $\rho$ about the same.

Comment: [Index calculus has a wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Index_calculus_algorithm). See that for a general description and links to more. I jotted down that example partly to have a semiserious case as an example I can refer to.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen At first, I want to thank you professor Lahtonen because of useful link and notations that you mentioned. I have learned from you that finite fields may seem hard, but with some sweet tricks. Because of this, I want to ask my question clearly. Consider $\gamma$ is an element in $\mathbb{F}_{\displaystyle{3^{23}}}$ such that its order is $47$. 
Now, consider the following polynomial
$$
\beta=\gamma^{22}+\gamma^{21}+\gamma^{19}+\gamma^{18}+\gamma^{15}-\gamma^{14}-\gamma^{13}+\gamma^{10}-\gamma^{9}-\gamma^{8}-\gamma^{7}+\gamma^{6}-\gamma^{3}-
\gamma+1
$$

Comment: $\gamma$ generates that field, so every element of $\Bbb{F}_{3^{23}}$ can be written as a polynomial in $\gamma$. Also, this expression does not specify $\beta$ uniquely because there are $46$ primitive roots of unity of order $47$, split into two conjugacy classes. This calculation may be one for the computers. I'm afraid I don't see tricks for handling such a $\beta$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen  Maybe, it was better to wrote 
$$
\gamma=\alpha^{\displaystyle{\frac{3^{23}-1}{47}}}
$$
One question. The following relation is the decomposition of the mentioned polynomial over $\mathbb{F}_3$. Now, how this spiting is used to find solution of question
$$
(\gamma^{3}+\gamma^{2}-\gamma+1) 
(\gamma^{19}+\gamma^{17}-\gamma^{16}+\gamma^{14}-\gamma^{12}-\gamma^{11}-\gamma^{10}+\gamma^{9}-\gamma^{8}+\gamma^{7}-\gamma^{6}-\gamma^{5}+\gamma^{4}-\gamma^{2}+1)
$$
Thanks