# How to solve $2^{53x} \equiv 3 \pmod{23}$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I tried to solve this congruence, but I don't understand how to find “?”

$2^{11} \equiv 1 \pmod{23}$ so

$53x \equiv ~?  \pmod{11}$

I know that “?” is equal to $8$, but I don't know how to find it, thank you!

Comment: So you want to know how to find that $8$ is a solution to $2^y\equiv_{23}3$?

Comment: +1 for showing that you know how to use the order of $2$ to simplify the question.

Comment: You accepted an answer that doesn't answer the above question. Please clarify what you meant to ask (and see the comments on the accepted answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$2^8\equiv 3 \mod23$$

$$2^{11}\equiv 1 \mod23$$

$$2^{11t}\times2^{8}\equiv 3 \mod23$$

$$2^{53x}\equiv 2^{11t+8}\equiv 3 \mod23$$

$$53x\equiv 8 \mod11$$

$$9x\equiv 8 \mod11$$

$$x\equiv 7 \mod11$$

$$x=7+11k$$

where $k \in Z$

Comment: This does not answer the question. OP already knows that $\,n=8\,$ works for $\,2^n\equiv 3.\,$ You simply verify that this works (which is trivial  modular arithmetic), But OP wants to know how to find such an $\,n,\,$ which is difficult in general.

Comment: @BillDubuque Agreed. I try to address just that. Not sure how much can be said in general because it is, after all, an instance of the DLP. I made it CW, because I half expect a suitable duplicate target to exist (and don't want points for contributions like this anyway).

Comment: @Jyrki Given that the OP has now accepted what they already claimed to know, it's not clear what they are asking. For hand computation we can use Shank's baby-giant step as [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3444644/242) to improve from a linear brute force search to sqrt of that (which here takes only $1$ step), but that's a bit overkill here for such small order $\,({\rm ord}(2) = 11)\,$ where brute force listing the powers of $2$ is easy enough already. But it's not overkill in the linked post (and the other linked there).

Comment: @BillDubuque Yeah. It is admittedly puzzling that the OP accepted an answer that didn't give them anything new, But, thanks for adding a link to an example of  baby step - giant step approach. I should have remembered that possibility as well.

Answer (score 0):

Finding the ???, or equivalently finding $y$ such that $2^y\equiv3\pmod{23}$, is an instance of [a discrete logarithm problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_logarithm). There is no universal efficient method for solving it. Thankfully $11$ is a small number, so you can brute force it.

---

If you want to see a trick then an ad hoc answer can be derived from the observation that
$$
3^3=27\equiv 2^2\pmod{23}.
$$
Leaving that as a hint :-)

> Plug in $3=2^y$, and solve $y$ from the resulting congruence modulo $11$.

---

Observations like the one above are the basis of an algorithm called [index calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Index_calculus_algorithm). For a (barely) pen-and-pencil-doable example of index calculus you may take a look at [this answer of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2289111/11619), partly prepared for referrals like this. That example works in the field $\Bbb{F}_{2^{10}}$. Meaning that the arithmetic is done modulo a polynomial (with coefficients modulo two) instead of modulo some prime $p$ like here. The principles are the same.